# How to update fragment in Swipe View with Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, event-listener

the following: I'm using [Swipe View with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). Works quite smooth so far.

The thing is: I have two fragments/tabs. Each contains a `ListView`. I can remove an item from the left list. When I swipe to the right I want to update the list adapter so the left-deleted item is shown.

I tried `onSwipeListerner`, `TabListener`, `onPageChangeListener` (and `on Resume()` in the fragment itself). Nothing worked... Either the function is not called or I don't get the fragment object.

Does anybody know how I can call a function in my `Fragment` class when I swipe to this tab/fragment?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried implementing an interface for your two fragments? If you create an interface in your left list and implement it in your right list, when you delete from the left list you can call your interface method in the fragment implementing the interface passing the removed item from the left list. . .

Comment: Actually After reviewing the http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html, it seems as if you need to create an interface in both of your fragments to communicate from the fragment to the parent activity. Then in the parent communicate the message to your other fragment. They have an example in that link.

Comment: It may be a little bit difficult to implement right away, i would suggest copying the bare minimum code from your current app and creating a new demo project to try implementing it. This way you can understand the very basics of the communication from fragment to activity to fragment

Comment: I read the article a second time and I think this is not really what I'm looking for. Its for dynamically adding fragments and so on. In my case everything is static...

Comment: Can you post your activity code where you add the fragments to the UI, including your viewpager class, as well as the two fragment classes. I think it will help me solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver

I believe this is what you are looking to accomplish. But I don't think your plan of action is the best.

I would create an interface in my fragment where items will be deleted from such as

```
 public class FragmentDeleteItemSharer extends Fragment{
     // Interface in Fragment
     public interface ShareDeletedItem{
          // Interface method you will call from this fragment
          public void shareItem(Object deletedItem);
     }// end interface


     // Instantiate the new Interface Callback
     ShareDeletedItem mCallback = null;

     // Override the onAttach Method
     @Override
     public void onAttach(Activity activity){
       super.onAttach(activity);

       try{ 
           // Attaches the Interface to the Activity
           // must add "implements ShareDeletedItem" in your 
           // Activity or this Exception is thrown
           mCallback = (ShareDeletedItem) activity;

       }catch(Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
     }// end onAttach()


     // the method which you use to 
     // remove an item from the current fragment's listview
     // where position is from yourlistViewAdapter.getSelectedItemPosition();
     public void removeListItem(int position){
            // using the item position, get the item in your object array
            Object objectToDelete = myObjects[position];
            // pass this information to removeItemFromArray
            // a method that creates a new object array from the data
            Object [] newObjectList = removeItemFromArray(myObjects, objectToDelete);

            // Then use the interface callback to tell activity item was deleted
            mCallback.shareItem(objectToDelete);

            // Call to the method where you update the UI with the Objects
            // Are you using an arrayList? Not sure but probably have 
            // an ArrayList<Objects> myObjects, as reference above
            updateUiWithData(newObjectList);
     }

 }// end this fragment
```

Then in your activity create an interface

```
 public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ShareDeletedItem{

    // Interface Object , must attach this interface to Fragment2, when its created
    UpdateFragment2 mCallback = null;

    // You must attach this interface to your Fragment2, when its created
    // you could do so with your view pager, create a method that adds each
    // fragment to the view pager, then call a new method like                   
    // addinterface(fragmentReference)

    public interface UpdateFragment2{
           // method to call in your Fragment that shows queue of deletes
           public void addItemtoList(Object newObject);
    }

   // Interface Callback from the Fragment that deletes an item
   public void shareItem(Object deletedItem){

         // call the interface method to share the item with the Fragment2
         mCallback.addItemToList(deletedItem);
   }

 }
```

Finally, Implement this interface in your Fragment2

```
  public class Fragment2 extends Fragment implements UpdateFragment2{

     // Interface Method in charge of giving this fragment the deleted item
     public void addItemToList(Object deletedItem){
         // TODO: Add the Item to the list you currently have
         // If the mObjects array is an array list
         mObjects.add(mObjects[mObjects.length + 1], deletedItem);
     }
  }
```

Depending on how you create your fragments with your view pager call

```
try{ 
   // or however you hold reference to the fragment
  mCallBack = (UpdateFragment2) Fragment2.class; 
}catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```

This is the Full of It. Hope this helps you understand that the interface way is the way to go. This is kind of difficult to help with no code from you but this is how it is done. The hardest part is adding the interface to the fragment when you create the fragments with you view pager. Good Luck

Comment: Did you get this resolved yet? Swipey tabs is really cool once it all works but it can be a real headache to work with.

Comment: For some reason, I think the scenario presented here looks similar to the problem I am facing. I am searching for a solution for days and I cannot solve a problem that involves interface, two fragments and its adapters, and the update of the recyclerView of the ReceiverFragment. I really appreciate if you guys could help me on this issue. Here is the link Stack Overflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464482/android-fragment-to-fragment-communication-update-recyclerview-of-the-receiver?noredirect=1#comment95738198_54464482