# How to update ListView in Fragment from FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have three Fragments, one of which has a ListView, which gets populated inside an Async Task (gets data from server as JSON). What I would like to do is call this Async Task when ever the tab is changed to the Fragment with the ListView.

I have a tabbed/swipeable interface and I have no clue where to make the call in the `FragmentActivity` to refresh the `ListView` when the user navigates to that `Fragment`.

Right now I am calling the Async Task like this `new LoadAllProducts().execute();` in the `onCreateView()` method of the Fragment which contains the `ListView`. I'm thinking I need a call to this Async Task in the onTabSelected() method of the `FragmentActivity`, but I am not sure how to make this call...any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

### EDIT 1:

Tried something like this as per in the answers:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
}
```

No luck, no errors thrown but also no refreshing of the data so I'm guessing LoadAllProducts() is not called.

### Edit 2:

Trying something like this now:
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

```
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

}
```

^Inside of Fragment. And the following inside the parent Activity:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Fragment frag = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(arg0.getPosition());

if (arg0.getPosition() == 1) {
    frag.onResume();
}
}
```

This shows no errors until you actually run the app and swipe to the tab at position one. Here is the LogCat. I'm really running out of ideas how to get this List to refresh when you swipe to its Fragment/Tab. :(

```
01-29 00:47:30.792: E/InputEventReceiver(2211): Exception dispatching input event.
01-29 00:47:30.792: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at com.geronimosoft.autotracker.activities.MAINSCREEN_Activity.onTabSelected(MAINSCREEN_Activity.java:436)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:572)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.setSelectedNavigationItem(ActionBarImpl.java:358)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at com.geronimosoft.autotracker.activities.MAINSCREEN_Activity$1.onPageSelected(MAINSCREEN_Activity.java:138)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:567)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:551)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2015)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7384)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2205)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1940)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-29 00:47:30.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2211):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 00:47:30.862: D/AndroidRuntime(2211): Shutting down VM
01-29 00:47:30.862: W/dalvikvm(2211): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at com.geronimosoft.autotracker.activities.MAINSCREEN_Activity.onTabSelected(MAINSCREEN_Activity.java:436)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:572)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.setSelectedNavigationItem(ActionBarImpl.java:358)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at com.geronimosoft.autotracker.activities.MAINSCREEN_Activity$1.onPageSelected(MAINSCREEN_Activity.java:138)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:567)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:551)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2015)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7384)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2205)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1940)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-29 00:47:30.932: E/AndroidRuntime(2211):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There isn't much I can post, I'm not getting any errors in my Async Task, all I need to do is call it when the user swipes to a specific tab...

Comment: May useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20107657/1318946

Comment: `onResume()` should be the correct place to refresh, since, when you change the tab, your ListView Fragment will be displayed, so `onResume()` should be called at that point.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav but it doesn't seem to do anything in onResume(). The list does not get refreshed...am I missing something? Anyway to force a refresh when you swipe to a tab?

Answer (score 0):

I would think on resume would get called when you navigate to the other tab.

I have not used tabs myself, but if so that is where I would put the async task.

Comment: Thanks Adam, looking into onResume() now. See my update to the original post, any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Comment: I am pretty sure calling life cycle stages is frowned upon. They happen on their own. Maybe call to your fragment manager to replace your fragment with a new instance instead? In the main activity on tabselected just replace the fragment. If you can do the list when you first create a fragment, recreate it torepeat the pprocess?