# Refresh the Tab Content while Sliding or Selecting in Android?

Tags: android

i want to know that how we can Refresh the Activity using Tab Swipe feature in android. below is my code:

```
        //Click & Sliding Control on Tabs

        tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
        {
            // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                // When swiping between pages OR select the corresponding tab
                switch (position)
                {
                    default:
                    case 0:
                        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();  
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

My **TAB1 Activity** Code is below: Please have a look as well:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    Context mContext;
    private GridView mGridView;
    public static String[] eatFoodyImages = {
            "https://media.giphy.com/media/T7VuyIFl3jimI/giphy.gif",
            "http://www.goodwp.com/large/201210/24514.jpg",
            "http://www.goodwp.com/mini/201210/24499.jpg",
            "https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/21/posts/19431/featured_image/CodeFeature.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/rFLNqWI.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/C9pBVt7.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/rT5vXE1.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/aIy5R2k.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/MoJs9pT.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/S963yEM.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/rLR2cyc.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/SEPdUIx.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/aC9OjaM.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/76Jfv9b.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/fUX7EIB.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/syELajx.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/COzBnru.jpg",
            "http://i.imgur.com/Z3QjilA.jpg",
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
        mGridView = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        mContext=getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mContext, eatFoodyImages));

        //Click Event on Images in GridView
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Pic" + (position + 1) +" Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

i am using **onPageSelected** which is working fine when click on Tab or Swipe the Tabs. For example if i display the **TOAST** then it works fine. just i don't know how to call Activity. Actually i just wants to perform Refresh as i have Gridview which contains the Pictures.

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20107657/2591002 ?

Comment: create a method in Fragment which will refresh the contentand call that method from onPageSelected . Simple !!

Comment: **@SweetWisherツ** Please have look on the Above code everything is there including Tab1 Activity. So how can we refresh that one while living on Main Activity ?

Comment: Can't you even give a **try** ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can declare public method in your Activity and invoke it.

Comment: **@Kirill Zotov** Yes, i do declare the Public Method in My Activity. i have update my Question Above. Please have a Look.

Answer (score 0):

It's so Simple.

> Create a method in Fragment which will refresh the content and call
>   that method from onPageSelected .

Code For your activity:

```
tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When swiping between pages OR select the corresponding tab
                switch (position) {
                    default:
                    case 0:
                        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                        tab1.refreshView();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Code for Fragment :

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment{

    public void refreshView(){
        // your code to refresh the content goes here
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you ツ